# If i created element in javascript and how call function when i click on the created element?

Tags: javascript

Something like this:

```
<html>
   <head></head>

   <body>
      <button onclick="elem()">Create element</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function elem() {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            div.id = 'myDiv';
            div.innerHTML = 'This is created div element with javascript';
         }

         var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
         myDiv.onclick = function() {
            alert('Hello');
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have problem. How call function when i clicik on the created element?

Comment: Move `myDiv.onclick` inside `elem()`

Answer (score 3):

either you need to add the click event when you create the element

```
function elem() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.id = 'myDiv';
    div.innerHTML = 'This is created div element with javascript';
    div.onclick = function() {
       alert('Hello');
    };
}
```

or you need to listen for the click event with event bubbling with an element that is a ancestor.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = function (evt) {  //there are better ways to add an event
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if(target.id==="myDiv") {
        alert("hello");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the event handler when you create the new element.  Otherwise the script will execute and attempt to assign the event handler before the `div` is attached to the DOM.

```
     function elem() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.id = 'myDiv';
        div.innerHTML = 'This is created div element with javascript';

        div.onclick = function() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
     }
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mve2T/

Comment: There is no jQuery here.  Also, he already does this: `document.body.appendChild(div);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `myDiv` code should exist insdie the `elem` function you can use also `addEventListener()` instead of 'onclick' for binding the handler on particular event. Something like this.

```
function elem() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.id = 'myDiv';
    div.innerHTML = 'This is created div element with javascript';

     var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        myDiv.addEventListener('click', function (){
        alert('hello'); 
    });
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QSMy5/)

Comment: `myDiv` is `null`.  Also, he does this inside the `elem()` function.

Answer (score 0):

you better add your event in your `elem` function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function elem() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.id = 'myDiv';
        div.innerHTML = 'This is created div element with javascript';
        div.onclick = function() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
     }
</script>
```

your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QSMy5/1/)

Comment: His `elem()` function is being called via a `<button>` in the HTML.